# Adding a custom template for extracting data in excel

Tags: asp.net, excel

I'm currently working on a project which one of its modules is to upload a custom excel file then my code should recognize the excel file's template.
then Users should be able to determine which data is put in which excel field.
I am writing this with asp.net mvc. and so far I'm screwed. anyone knows where should I start? or what library I should Use? I'd really appreciate the help

Comment: This question is waay too broad. But start by looking at [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Fetching Excel File data in c# , I recommend you to study about Aspose.Cells, It is a third party Dll, There API is Easy to understand and Very Easy to implement.
In that you can Fetch Your Excel Files as

1. Workbook - Full Excel File
2. Worksheets - Sheets Inside Excel File
3. Cells - Group of Excel Cell
4. Cell - A single Cell which you can access in the form of 2D Array like A1 Cell of Excel Sheet Will be Cell[0][0];
5. It also gives you facility to put formulaes, Sorting, Blank Row Deletion and many more Things
6. Here you can easily Export your Excel sheet in a DataTable and vice Versa

Have a look at it is Easier to use.Thanks

Comment: @NimaKhaki If you are satosfied with the help please accepr it as answer so that more user will get benefit from it thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Showcase
this library was close to what I needed.